# Not able to write to log file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to redirect output to both console and log file. But I am not able to push the output of line #11 (get process id) into log; though it perfectly works for line #08.

```
# Get script name
$me = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name

# Set name of logfile to that of scriptname
$Logfile = $me -replace ".ps1", "_$(Get-Date -DisplayHint Date -Format "dd-MMM-yyyy").log"

# log with color on screen:
log "Script `"$me`" has been initiated on $(Get-Date -DisplayHint DateTime -Format "dd-MMM-yyyy @ HH:mm:ss:ms tt")" Yellow

# Get process id
log "$( Get-Process "mysqld" | ft id -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize )"

# Function to redirect to console and logfile
function log($string, $color)
{
   if ($Color -eq $null) {$color = "white"}
   Write-Host $string -foregroundcolor $color
   $string | Out-File -Filepath $LogFile -append
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace

```
log "$( Get-Process "mysqld" | ft id -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize )
```

by

```
Get-Process "mysqld" | ForEach {log $_.id}
```

does it do what you want to do?

Comment: Get-Process "mysqld" | ForEach {log "Process id is : $($_.id)" Red} - also worked.